# Minimum API Level 14 required,error + No emulator found error to make Android 2.2 application?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am following a series of video tutorials to learn android and making my own Android Application.
According to video,i m suppose to download Android 2.2 from SDK Manager and create emulator for the same.
Now,for creating a new Android Application Project in Eclipse ,Which

- "Minimum Required SDK",
- "Target SDK","Compile With" and
- "Theme"

should i choose ?
Please help me OUT..!

Comment: Target SDK chose api 23 and minimum sdk chose api 10 to support gingerbread.

Comment: But the eclipse version i am using:                                                        
"Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200" does not have option of Target SKD for API 23,it have up to API 21.. Also what should i Choose for "Compile with" option...It have 2 options:1)API 8 2)Google API 8

Comment: eclipse version is not related to which min version you choose for the android sdk, as long as you have the api 23 development support libraries you are fine :)

Comment: ok got it..But what should i choose in "Compile with " option.

Comment: have you installed java sdk jre etc?

Comment: yes in SDK Manager Android 4.1.2 and android 2.2 is installed

Comment: not the android sdk, i'm talking about java sdk and java run time environments, compile with expects which java sdk version to use to compile

Comment: yes the latest java 8.0.45